# SSH Connection refused from remote host

Tags: centos, ssh

I have 2 VPS running on CentOS 6, Server1 and Server2. I can access both servers with SSH from my PC, but when I connect from Server2 to Server1 using this command:

```
ssh root@xxx.xx.xxx.x -p 22
```

I get this error:

> Unable to connect to xxx.xx.xxx.x:22: Connection refused

This is only happening for Server2. Server1 can connect to Server2 without any problems.

I am sure my SSH port is 22, I have stopped iptables on both servers and I have checked host allow and deny config. How can I fix this?

Comment: When you access from home, are you using root also?

Comment: have you check the port 22 by doing port scanning?

Comment: Can you print the verbose output of the ssh connection with option -v in command ssh?

Comment: Can you post `tail /var/log/secure` immediately after failing from server1? (You may want to censor some private information)

Answer (score 2):

First to ssh to another server on port 22 you dont need the -p switch. It is the default port and ssh would able to complete without specifying that. Basically you want to see if port 22 is open between the servers. A simple telnet client should suffice.
Do the following command on shell prompt.

```
telnet servername 22
```

If you see some text like openssh and then back to shell prompt, then it is not firewall issue.

Answer (score 1):

I can at least tell you where it is stuck. Three common debugging approach would be in this order.

```
ssh -vvvv root@<XX.XX.XX.XX>
```

Check where it is throwing error after giving the password. Use pastebin if you want us to see.

```
strace -ffttTo /tmp/strace.out ssh root@<XX.XX.XX.XX>
```

Again use pastebin if you want us to see the strace data.

Last and most lethal,

```
tcpdump  -s0 -i ethX 'port 22' -w /tmp/ssh.pcap 
ssh root@<XX.XX.XX.XX>
```

When ssh fails, hit ctrl-c to stop tcpdump. Obviously, you need to ssh from different konsole.

Don't give this data to us, people will be able to see everything.

Answer (score 0):

Check [whether a root login is permited](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/SecuringSSH) on server 2, if it is run **ssh** with the **-vvv** flag, you should see what's causing the failure.

Comment: You would not get "connection refused" -- just "authentication failed". "Connection refused" means that ssh was not able to establish a tcp connection.